# iTunes starting playlist in different order than view

Tags: itunes, music, playlist

In iTunes 12 I am able to sort the songs using different filters and sort options. In my basic configuration my songs are sorted by artists and in the artists view, they are sorted by year (selection in upper right corner: artist, year).

[image: view settings for albums]

However, if I just play all the songs or albums of a given artist using the play button next to the artist's name (at the top of the page) the playlist is started at the album showed in the upper "global" cover, but not in chronogical order:

[image: Global play button does not start playlist in chronological order]

Is there a way to combine view and playlist order? How can I update the album showed in the upper "summary" containing the artist's global play button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin from Stopped rather than Paused.
Play, then Alt/click the play button to Stop. You'll see the currently-playing track then disappears from the header...

Paused [image]
Stopped [image]

Then Play by double-clicking your chosen first Song, or choose an artist & hit Spacebar. It should then play in the visible order, assuming you don't have shuffle on.

Though you're right... I hadn't ever tried playing by hitting that Play arrow by the Artist name - it always wants to start on Slow Night, So Long.
Both the other methods work, though.

<sup>*Looks like you're missing Day Old Belgian Blues, btw - great Live EP, chronologically follows Aha Shake*</sup>

Comment: Hint for upcoming readers: Instead of pressing space bar, the Play key on the keyboard does exactly the same.

Comment: The Play F-Key is Play/Pause, not Play/Stop, just to clarify - & this only works from Stop.